# Use of Selenium IDE or Selenium Webdriver for my case?

Tags: testing, selenium, ide, webdriver

I am new to Selenium, and I have been ask to create a test case in which I need to get data from outside like xls or notepad, and include in the testcase, so without any manual input whole testcase can run. However I have tried many different method found on google I was not able to perform this action. I was wondering if it is possible with Selenium IDE or Selenium Webdriver. I do not have knowledge of Java, so I am avoiding Selenium webdriver, however please suggest me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

i do not have idea about web driver but u can read xml file using selenium ide
just follow the steps
1. Attached the js file in your selenium core extensions(in option menu) 
2. Now restart firefox
and copy this example code

```
<tr><td>forXml</td>
<td>file:///C:/Users/path/filename.xml</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>open</td><td>http://www.google.co.uk</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>type</td>
<td>q</td>
<td>${phrase}</td></tr><tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>btnG</td>
<td></td></tr><tr><td>endForXml</td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr>
```

sample xml data

```
<testdata>
    <vars phrase="bbc news"/>
    <vars phrase="computers"/>
    <vars phrase="mobile phones"/>
    <vars phrase="insurance &amp; loans"/>
</testdata>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I'm still getting some error message while executing above commands. 1. Which JS file I have to attach to it, and 2. it says unknown command forXml, I'm sorry but please bare with me for this.

Comment: Download the sel block add-on in your Mozilla firefox from this [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/) make sure your are working on Mozilla 19.0.0 version as this sel block add-on has a compatiblity issue with the latest version of Mozilla 20.0.1

Comment: Check this [link](http://unmesh.me/2012/12/04/data-driven-testing-with-selenium-ide/selide/) also you may get an idea

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, now I am able to use Selenium a little bit. You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably possible within the IDE itself, but I believe the problem of not knowing Java is a *poor* excuse to totally avoid it.

Java with the Selenium WebDriver API will give you much more **flexibility**, **reliability**,  and many more **possibilities** of what you can do.

If you take the time to learn Java **and** the WebDriver API, you will be glad you did, it will give you so much more knowledge and experience that you can use in the future, even to advance your career.